# Is WCF recommended to use with WPF and MVVM to retrieve data from SQL Server?

Tags: wpf, sql-server, wcf

I am building a desktop application that will be used on local network, with SQL Server as database.

This application would have around 50 users top at the same time. In what particular scenario would I need to use WCF service? Is it recommended to create a WCF service on the server computer where database would reside, so we connect to this server through WCF service, instead of connecting to the database directly? What is the recommended way to connect to SQL Server data and why?

**Edit**: Let me explain in more detail. I have used WCF Ria services before, so I know how they work. Lets assume that WCF services works in same way. The question was directed toward why would we use WCF instead of directly connecting to database? I didnt want to specify my current application requirement, since I would get a specific answer for specific requirement. My goal was to understand in general why and when would you yse one instead of another. And I have received satisfying answers so far.

It appears to me that general consensus is to use WCF only if there would be a demand of another type of application, which would use web access to get data from service. Also, if I understood correctly, from security point of view, there is no difference between the two.

There would be a statistical app in the future that uses web to provide read-only statistics to user, and naturally some service will be required for this task (application has no specific client in mind, it will be offered to lots of clients). Since I need some demo application to be done very rapidly for particular clients, then I am thinking to neglect the service part, and make a proper layering (WPF->VM->Model->EF, so later I would just insert service between the model and EF. I guess it should not take too much time to make WPF app running with inserted layer. I am also postponing the service because of next reason: since HTML5 is (going to be) main technology for web, and there is a possibility that SL will be abandoned as technology (which I have been using), the logical decision would be to choose HTML5 over SL. But since I am totally unfamiliar with HTML5 and its requirements, I am not sure if WCF service is the best choice for it, and this is also one of the reasons to postpone the decision of choosing the service type (along with requirement to make the desktop demo app as fast as possible).

Comment: Why not just connect to the database? Why even _consider_ using WCF?

Comment: This is my question actually. :) Do I need WCF, or is it totally sufficient? Is it more common scenario to use WCF or connect to database directly? What are the pros/cons? Is there some other option that is recommended?

Comment: Do you need WAS? How about WF? Maybe you should try WIF?

Comment: If you don't know whether you need them or not, then you don't need them. Same for WCF.

Comment: Two reasons might advocate using a WCF service layer: (1) you want to shield your database from direct access by an application, or (2) you want to potentially build more than one client (e.g. a WPF app today, a Silverlight app tomorrow, and a ASP.NET MVC app after that) - a WCF service nicely supports that (and saves you from having to write the data access code multiple times)

Comment: @John Saunders You got me confused with those 3 letter acronyms. How one googles for WAS? :) anyway, since WF and WIF I do not need, lets say that WAS is also not required.

Comment: My point was that you don't need WCF, either, since you have no requirement for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a better way to consider the question is whether you should abstract your database and data access layer from the application using a service interface. You could use WCF and SOAP or you could use a REST based HTTP service, the choice of technology is secondary to whether the current or future requirements of your application indicate that an additional layer of abstraction is warrented.

Reasons you might consider using a service interface instead of directly connecting to the SQL database include but are not limited to:

- Ease of supporting multiple operating systems/client UIs
- Ability to evolve the data/service interface separately from your database schema
- Isolate application from changes to database schema or location (you don't have to redeploy change to application, only change internals of the services it is calling)
- If data could be used by other systems, you have a standard means of allowing these systems to interface with the data your application is managing
- Reduced SQL database connection security concerns (only service identity connects to database, allowing you to use a variety of authentication/authorization strategies on the client side)

The trade off you are looking at is the time/cost/complexity of implementing a service interface versus the flexibility and mantainability benefits you will gain. You should evaluate the needs of your application and your customer before you make a decision on whether to connect directly to your data store using ADO.NET or use a service layer.

You should take a look at the Microsoft [Service Layer Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658090.aspx) as they cover a lot of the considerations to take into account.

Comment: Isolation of the UI layer from the DAL could be achieved by using an ORM tool. This introduces all benefits you described without having an application service layer in between. Remember you need to host your web services somewhere and it is not an easy task sometimes unless you already have a web side of your application that need these web services too. Also I am not sure why do you write WCF or REST since WCF supports REST perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need to create a reusable service, I can't think of a reason to add a WCF layer, unless you are just looking for a reason to do it.  I think you can just go with some sort of ORM like EF or nHibernate and be happy.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for WCF is security.  If the client connects directly to the DB then the client must be given rights on tables.   The client can hack into the connection and use TSQL directly.   You must expose port 1433 to the network in a single tier application.  With WCF there is not direct access from the client to SQL.   It is not just more secure in general but you can have more granular security.  .NET service code can enforce row level security.   A table only has column level security.   If this is business on a private network and you don't expect anyone would try and hack into your db then client connecting directly to the SQL server is easier to build.   With server side service the other factor is a change to server side code is one spot so you don't have to update 50 devices.

Comment: -1: Nonsense. It's possible to give the clients access only to certain views and/or stored procedures.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Wake up.  Port 1433 open is a whole different security exposure.  Show me a view or stored procedure that protects at the row level.

Comment: First of all, if we agree that your "rights on tables" argument is false, then you should edit your answer to remove it. Second, nobody said anything about column-level security (though Views get you that). Finally, "the client could use TSQL directly"? The client can do that without any hacking at all. It's up to the DBA to ensure that the database is secure regardless of whether or not someone is  using the database.

Comment: @JohnSaunders So what if it did not say "via a view" the statement is still accurate. Business rule that Jonny can only see PK 1-100 and Sally can only see PK 101-200 on TableX. Jonny can only edit PK 1-20. How are you doing to enforce that as a DBA if you give the user TSQL and direct access to SQL?

Comment: By only giving access to stored procedures which contain the rules.

Comment: @JohnSaunders For many businsess applications that is a LOT of stored procudures.  If Jonny now has authority for PK 21 I prefer to handle that logic in a business data layer rather than wait for DBA to revise a stored producedure.  The app I am responsible for would require 1000+ updates updates a day to the stored producedures if that was how row security was handled.  On SO you can only edit your own comment.  You think SO handles row security with stored procedures?

Comment: I don't know, and this is pointless. Most applications I've worked with put that sort of thing either in a business layer or in the database. In neither case is a web service required.